# Selected option is not highlighted

Tags: html, angularjs, select

When ever i delete any option i am preselecting 'Product'. Even though it is selected it is not highlighted. One new option with value "? string:{{lastSelectedOption}} ?" is showing up.

> Html

```
 <select class="mapping-select" id="SelectId" ng-model="table" name="classesList" size="20" >
                <!-- <option value="? string:{{selectedTable}} ?" style="display:none"></option> -->
                <option value="" style="display:none" ></option>
                <option value="Product" ng-click="selectTable('Product', 'Product')" ng-selected="preSelect">Product</option>
                <optgroup style="font-style: normal;" label="Prices">
                            <option value="{{pa.table}}" id="com.jcatalog.product.Prices:{{$index}}" ng-repeat="pa in tableLists.PricesList track by $index" ng-click="selectTable('Prices', 'Price', $index, tableLists.PricesList)">
                                {{pa.table}}({{$index+1}})
                            </option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup style="font-style: normal;" label="ProductAttributeValues">
                            <option value="{{pav.table}}" id="com.jcatalog.product.ProductAttributeValue:{{$index}}" ng-repeat="pav in tableLists.ProductAttributeValuesList track by $index" ng-click="selectTable('ProductAttributeValues', 'ProductAttributeValue', $index, tableLists.ProductAttributeValuesList)">
                                {{pav.table}}({{$index+1}})
                            </option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup style="font-style: normal;" label="ClassificationAssignment">
                            <option value="{{cg.table}}" id="com.jcatalog.product.ClassificationAssignment:{{$index}}" ng-repeat="cg in tableLists.ClassificationAssignmentsList track by $index" ng-click="selectTable('Product2ClassificationGroup', 'ClassificationAssignment', $index, tableLists.ClassificationAssignmentsList)">
                                {{cg.table}}({{$index+1}})
                            </option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup style="font-style: normal;" label="ProductRelations">
                            <option value="{{pr.table}}" id="com.jcatalog.product.ProductRelations:{{$index}}" ng-repeat="pr in tableLists.ProductRelationsList track by $index" ng-click="selectTable('ProductRelations', 'ProductRelation', $index, tableLists.ProductRelationsList)">
                                {{pr.table}}({{$index+1}})
                            </option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup style="font-style: normal;" label="ContractedProduct">
                            <option value="{{cp.table}}" id="com.jcatalog.product.ContractedProduct:{{$index}}" ng-repeat="cp in tableLists.ContractedProductList track by $index" ng-click="selectTable('ContractedProduct', 'ContractedProduct',$index, tableLists.ContractedProductList)">
                                {{cp.table}}({{$index+1}})
                            </option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
```

> Option Deletion

```
$scope.selectTable = function (tname, otname, rowNo, list) {
  getTableData(tname, otname);
  $scope.selectedTable = otname;
  $scope.rowId = rowNo+1;
  $scope.selectedTableList = list;
}

$scope.acceptDeletetion = function () {
      var id;
      if($scope.selectedTable != 'Product'){
        if($scope.selectedTable && $scope.rowId){
          id = $scope.rowId;
          $scope.selectedTableList.splice(id-1, 1);
          updateList($scope.selectedTable, id);
            $scope.preSelect = true;
        } 
      } else {
        growl.error("You can't delete Product table");
      } 
    }
```

[image: First image shows how select tag is looking when option is deleted]

[image: Second image shows Product option selection]

Could anyone help me why this new otion is adding and how can i avoid that?

Comment: can you show your html code

Comment: `One new option with value "? string:{{lastSelectedOption}} ?" is showing up.` where is it displayed? is this `lastSelectedOption` a scope variable?

Comment: @DivyaMV, that is not a scope variable.When i debug empty space i got a new option with value "? string:{{lastSelectedOption}} ?". why i  referred was that is not a constant string it was coming based on last selected value to remove

Comment: @DivyaMV, you can see first option in second image which is not there in html code. Here i am saying that option is adding automatically

Comment: I think your dropdown binding code is wrong, did you read the angularjs documents?

Comment: you have assigned `display:none` for the dropdown 1st option  `<option value="" style="display:none" ></option>`, it's will not display anything, then  why you need that line? please remove that line.

Comment: @RameshRajendran, Could you explain what happed to binding value?

Comment: @RameshRajendran, on first load it is taking empty value to remove that i added that option

Comment: okay , i have some question for you, where is the `selectTable` function? can you show me your error print(console message)? also what you mean the `track by $index`???

Comment: @RameshRajendran, I didn't get which console message. track by $index will allow repetative array also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73050/discussion-between-anusha-nilapu-and-ramesh-rajendran).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is gone, once i remove the `ng-model="table"` directive in your dropdownlist.

> I think the problem accrued for the model name `table` value is undefined in loading time, so it takes a object and also it sets a default value for your dropdown,So you got a white space**(you can see the undefined value in rendered html code, see the below image)** . that is a issue. good luck .

[image]